# How to read a String from a txt file and store it into a char array java

Tags: java, arrays, string, char

So I am trying to read a txt file into a char array and print out the contents, but I only get the first index of the String to print out. The contents of the file are "EADBC"

```
     public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
     {

    char [] correctAnswers = new char [20];
    String [] studentName = new String[5];
    char [][] studentAnswers = new char [20][20];

    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println ("Welcome to the Quiz Grading System \n");
    System.out.println ("Please Enter the name of the file that contains the correct answers");

    Scanner answerFile = new Scanner (new File (sc.next() + ".txt"));

    int i = 0;
    int fillLvl = 0;
    String answer;
    while (answerFile.hasNext() )
    {
        answer = answerFile.next();
        correctAnswers[i] = answer.charAt(i);
        i++;
        fillLvl = i;
    }
    answerFile.close();

    System.out.println("Correct Answers: ");
    for(int j = 0; j < fillLvl; j++)
    {
        System.out.println(correctAnswers[j]);
    }
```

Comment: `answerFile.next();` is going to return the next *Token* being `EADBC`, so if that is all that is in the file then it will loop no further.  Try reading this String and then split it.  Try running it in a debugger.

Comment: I tried doing something like:                                                                  String answer;                                                                                                        
        while (answerFile.hasNext() )
        {
            answer = answerFile.next();
            for(int i = 0; i < answer.length(); i++)
            {
                correctAnswers[i] = answer.charAt(i);
                i++;
            }
        }

Comment: ... and ? What happens?

Comment: I only get it to print out E D C, I don't get every index in the string I want into the array

Comment: You are increment `i` twice - remove the second `i++`

Comment: 'new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path))).toCharArray()'
This one liner does what you want!

Answer (score 1):

To read from a text file and convert into an array:

```
File file = new File("C:\\Users\\dell\\Desktop\\rp.txt");

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

String st;
char[] string1={};
int size = 0;

//reads the string and converts into array
while ((st = br.readLine()) != null){
    string1 = st.toCharArray();
    size = st.length();
}

//For printing
for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
    System.out.println(string1[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside while loop use like this..

```
    while (answerFile.hasNext() )
    {
        answer = answerFile.next();
        int j = 0;
        while(answer != null && !answer.isEmpty() && j < answer.length()){
            correctAnswers[i] = answer.charAt(j);
            i++;
            j++;
            fillLvl = i;
        }
    }
```

It is always recommended to use FileReader, BufferedReader to perform file operation;

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, read once and print them simple. Don't read them into a string and split them and again to a char.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("\\path\\to\\file.extension"))
);

int c;
while((c = reader.read()) != -1) {
    char character = (char) c;
    System.out.println(character);
}       

reader.close();
```